# How do you create a message queue service for the scope of a specific Kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes

I have a parallel Kubernetes job with 1 pod per work item (I set parallelism to a fixed number in the job YAML).

All I really need is an ID per pod to know which work item to do, but Kubernetes doesn't support this yet (if there's a workaround I want to know).

Therefore I need a message queue to coordinate between pods. I've successfully followed the example in the Kubernetes documentation here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/

However, the example there creates a `rabbit-mq` **service**. I typically deploy my tasks as a job. I don't know how the lifecycle of a job compares with the lifecycle of a service.

It seems like that example is creating a permanent message queue service. But I only need the message queue to be in existence for the lifecycle of the job.

It's not clear to me if I need to use a service, or if I should be creating the rabbit-mq container as part of my job (and if so how that works with parallelism).

Comment: What is wrong with using the pod name as the pod id? They are always unique.

Comment: Pod names are unique, but there's no way to convert that unique 5-digit hash into an index number needed to know which work item to process. I tried using the position of the pod's unique name in "Pod Created" events, but when you get jobs with many pods (20+ish) kubernetes aggregates the events list making that hack unusable.

Comment: `But I only need the message queue to be in existence for the lifecycle of the job.` Do you mean by it that your job-queue should be in a `Job`? Do I understand correctly that you need to find a way to get/generate/create unique numerical ID for each pod that will take a work order from a queue?

Comment: Creating a unique numerical ID (a counter) for each pod would solve the problem elegantly. I've looked high and low for a way to do this that doesn't involve spawning a whole distributed database to achieve it, but found nothing.